# discord.py - How to wait for user input that can be different?

Tags: discord, discord.py, bots

First time posting here, but I just couldn't find what I'm looking for or wrap my head around it.

As of now, I have this:

````
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content == '!generate':
        await message.channel.send(f"{message.author.mention}\n"
                                   f"Sample question: (**Important**: Type a \"!\" in front):\n```"
                                   "> A\n> B\n> C\n> D```")

        def check(m):
            return m.content == '!A' and m.channel == message.channel

        msg = await client.wait_for('message', check=check)
        await message.channel.send('Correct!'.format(msg))
````

So if the user inputs "!generate!", they get a question and a list of available answers. Now the bot already successfully waits for an answer, but only if it's A ("!A") does it actually respond further.

How can I change this so it can be any answer from the list, in this case A, B, C or D?

I already tried this:

```
def check(m):
            sample_list = ['!A', '!B', '!C', '!D']
            return m.content == f'{sample_list[0:3]}' and m.channel == message.channel
```

But that didn't work. To be fair, I'm very new to python and have barely any clue of what I'm doing, so I might be making some stupidly obvious mistake here.

But anyway, I hope this gives a good enough picture of what I'm trying to achieve. I appreciate any help! Thank you!

Comment: Now there are quite a few ways to go around this. So the reason return m.content == f'{sample_list[0:3}' and m.channel == message.channel didn't work first there is a bracket missing. also u should run it as m.content in sample_list it would run better

Comment: more ordered would be like for i in sample_list if m.content==i return m.content==i and the remains stuff you can add a else statement as well in case the other person types something else.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for :

````py
@bot.command()
async def generate(ctx):
    options = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
    already_sent_res = None  # Safe to remove, used for demo

    await ctx.send(
        f"{ctx.author.mention}\n"
        f'Sample question: (**Important**: Type a "!" in front):\n```'
        "> A\n> B\n> C\n> D```"
    )

    def check(m):
        return (
            m.content.startswith("!")
            and m.content.lower()[1:] in options
            and m.channel.id == ctx.channel.id
        )

    while True:
        msg = await bot.wait_for("message", check=check)
        # msg.content now contains the option. You may now proceed to code here
        # The below code from here are used for demonstration and can be safely removed
        if already_sent_res is None:
            sent_message = await ctx.send(
                f"**{str(msg.author.name)}** has chosen option **{str(msg.content).upper()[1:]}**"
            )
            already_sent_res = not None
        else:
            await sent_message.edit(
                f"**{str(msg.author.name)}** has chosen option **{str(msg.content).upper()[1:]}**"
            )
````

Here I used command handling with `bot.command()` instead of listening under `on_message` it is fine, you can use any which you are comfortable with.

The above code will result in the following :
[image: result]

Remember that the bot will keep on listening for `message` event in the channel so be sure to have a timeout or an abort command.

Here's the full code I used incase you need it :

````py
import discord
import os
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", case_insensitive=True)


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f"Sucessfully logged in as {bot.user}")


@bot.command()
async def generate(ctx):
    options = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
    already_sent_res = None  # Safe to remove, used for demo

    await ctx.send(
        f"{ctx.author.mention}\n"
        f'Sample question: (**Important**: Type a "!" in front):\n```'
        "> A\n> B\n> C\n> D```"
    )

    def check(m):
        return (
            m.content.startswith("!")
            and m.content.lower()[1:] in options
            and m.channel.id == ctx.channel.id
        )

    while True:
        msg = await bot.wait_for("message", check=check)
        # msg.content now contains the option. You may now proceed to code here
        # The below code from here are used for demonstration and can be safely removed
        if already_sent_res is None:
            sent_message = await ctx.send(
                f"**{str(msg.author.name)}** has chosen option **{str(msg.content).upper()[1:]}**"
            )
            already_sent_res = not None
        else:
            await sent_message.edit(
                f"**{str(msg.author.name)}** has chosen option **{str(msg.content).upper()[1:]}**"
            )


bot.run(os.getenv("DISCORD_TOKEN"))
````